# Bonferroni Correction When Using Dates as Data Points

Tags: t-test, bonferroni

I have a test and control group in which I tested the impact of a sale on baseline revenue across a 3 week period (test received sale, control did not).

```
    Control Test
1/1/2017    4   3
1/2/2017    3   4
1/3/2017    1   3
1/4/2017    2   3
1/5/2017    2   4
1/6/2017    1   7
1/7/2017    10  3
1/8/2017    2   3
1/9/2017    2   3
1/10/2017   2   3
1/11/2017   3   4
1/12/2017   1   5
1/13/2017   4   3
1/14/2017   3   4
1/15/2017   2   4
1/16/2017   1   4
1/17/2017   5   3
1/18/2017   3   4
1/19/2017   2   4
1/20/2017   1   6
1/21/2017   5   5
1/22/2017   7   5
```

I am using an independent t-test to analyze.  My question: Since I am measuring across multiple days, do I require a Bonferroni (or some other) correction?

The p-value is .037873 which is currently sig. but would not be using a correction.

Comment: There is only one test. Bonferroni corrections apply to multiple tests .

Comment: Hi Adam - so it would be statistically correct to run ONE independent t test across multiple days without any corrections

Comment: Yes, make it a paired test as well.

Comment: Were you checking each day/interval with some idea of ending the test early?

Comment: Why paired?  There are two different sets of  stores within test and control groups?

Comment: We only had a sale window for the allotted time

Comment: Unclear why the assumption is that the two groups (consisting of two separate sets of stores) would qualify for a paired comparison?